# ちゃんと帯付きだ！ meaning

Tags: grammar, kanji, pronunciation, readings, slang

This is translated as "in original cover"
Is this a common saying? and how is the kanji combo read?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they are talking about a book, 帯 refers to this type of paper:

> #### [Obi (publishing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obi_(publishing))
>
> An obi (Japanese: 帯) is a strip of paper looped around a book or other product.
>
> Many books in Japan are supplied with an obi, which is normally added outside any dust jacket. However, a book in a slipcase may have an obi around the slipcase.

See [the second definition on jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B8%AF), too.

Some collectors like obi, but they are often thrown away because they are nuisance when reading and usually only contain unimportant marketing phrases.

帯付き is read おびつき ("with an obi", "obi attached").

Comment: Thank you! I never knew what those were called, and now I do.